# Swift. Protocol type as dictionary key

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have been thinking about a way to use a Protocol type as a dictionary key. I made a simple test code in the playground:

```
//Custom Protocol conforms to Hashable
protocol Transport: Hashable {
   var name: String {get set}
   var quantity: Int {get set}
}

//Transport Protocol extension
extension Transport {
   var hashValue: Int {
      return name.hashValue ^ quantity.hashValue
   }
}
//Equatable Protocol (Since Hashable conforms to Equatable)
func ==<T:Transport>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

//Struct Car
struct Car: Transport {
   var name: String = ""
   var quantity: Int = 1

   init(name: String, quantity: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.quantity = quantity
   }
}
//Struct Plane
struct Plane: Transport {
   var name: String = ""
   var quantity: Int = 1

   init(name: String, quantity: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.quantity = quantity
   }
}

let t1 = Car(name: "Ford", quantity: 10)
let t2 = Plane(name: "Airbus", quantity: 2)
```

**Next line gives an error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Car' and 'Plane'**

```
if t1 == t2 {
   print("It's the same transport")
}
```

**Next line gives this error: Using 'Transport' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported**

```
var arrayOfTransports = [Transport:[Int]]()
```

What I am trying to do is to compare structures that conform to 'Transport' Protocol, and be able to use these structs as Dictionary keys.

Comment: This is a variant of [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – you cannot use `Transport` as a type that conforms to `Transport` or `Hashable`.